# Размещение дибаунсера в методах класса

Tags: javascript, методы, класс

Всем привет. Есть некий класс, вызывающий на странице виджет для добавления/удаления товаров в корзину после нажатия кнопки "добавить в корзину". Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
    class ToBasket {
    constructor(element) {
        this.module = element;
        this.i = 1;
        this.basketBtn = this.module.querySelector('.j-kt-basket-button');
        this.plusBtn = this.module.querySelector('.j-basket-counter-plus');
        this.minusBtn = this.module.querySelector('.j-basket-counter-minus');
        this.productID = this.module.getAttribute('data-product-id');
        this.bind();
    }

    bind = () => {
        this.showCounterOnLoad();
        this.addToBasket();
        this.removeFromBasket();
    }

    addToBasket = () => {
        this.plusBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
            ++this.i;
            document.querySelector('.j-basket-counter-counter').innerText = this.i;
            BX.ajax.runAction('citfact:sitecore.basket.update', {data: {itemId: this.productID, quantity: this.i}}).then(() => {
                    BX.onCustomEvent('OnBasketChange');
            });
        });
    }

    removeFromBasket = () => {
        this.minusBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
            --this.i;
            BX.ajax.runAction('citfact:sitecore.basket.update', {data: {itemId: this.productID, quantity: this.i}}).then(() => {
                BX.onCustomEvent('OnBasketChange');
            });
            if (this.i > 0) {
                document.querySelector('.j-basket-counter-counter').innerText = this.i;
            } else {
                document.querySelector('.j-basket-counter').style.display = 'none';
                this.basketBtn.querySelector('span').textContent = 'В корзину';
                this.basketBtn.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
                this.basketBtn.classList.remove('active');
                this.basketBtn.classList.add('add_to_cart');
            }
        });
    }

    showCounterOnLoad = () => {
        BX.ajax.runAction('citfact:sitecore.product.isBasket', {data: {itemId: this.productID}}).then((result) => {
            BX.onCustomEvent('OnBasketChange');
            if (result.data > 0) {
                this.basketBtn.querySelector('span').textContent = 'В корзине';
                this.basketBtn.href = '/personal/cart/';
                this.basketBtn.classList.add('active');
                this.basketBtn.classList.remove('add_to_cart');
                document.querySelector('.j-basket-counter').style.display = 'block';
                document.querySelector('.j-basket-counter-counter').innerText = result.data;
                this.i = result.data;
            }
        });
    }
}

export const initToBasket = () => {
        const list = [...document.querySelectorAll('.j-card-item-container')];
        list.forEach((element) => {
            new ToBasket(element);
        })
}
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: в методы addToBasket и removeToBasket нужно добавить дибаунсер, чтобы предотвратить излишние запросы к серверу, которые происходят на каждый клик.

Я пробую делать вот так:

```
removeFromBasket = () => {
        function remove() {
                --this.i;
                BX.ajax.runAction('citfact:sitecore.basket.update', {data: {itemId: this.productID, quantity: this.i}}).then(() => {
                    BX.onCustomEvent('OnBasketChange');
                });
                if (this.i > 0) {
                    this.modulet.querySelector('.j-basket-counter-counter').innerText = this.i;
                } else {
                    this.module.querySelector('.j-basket-counter').style.display = 'none';
                    this.basketBtn.querySelector('span').textContent = 'В корзину';
                    this.basketBtn.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
                    this.basketBtn.classList.remove('active');
                    this.basketBtn.classList.add('add_to_cart');
                }
        };

        function debounce( callback, delay ) {
            let timeout;
            return function() {
                clearTimeout( timeout );
                timeout = setTimeout( callback, delay );
            }
        };

        this.minusBtn.addEventListener('click', debounce(remove, 1000));
    }
```

но тогда внутри функции remove теряется контекст this.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как правильно?

Comment: "чтобы предотвратить излишние запросы к серверу" - где предотвращение?

Comment: после фразы "я пробую делать вот так"

Comment: `debounce(this.remove.bind(this), 1000)`

Comment: А почему бы при нажатии на кнопку не блокировать её (`disabled`), а после завершения запроса, разблокировать?

Comment: @Igor в этом случае я ловлю ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')

Comment: @Deonis собственно, то же самое практически выходит, просто надо установить интервал для прослушивания и перехвата ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте передать в `debounce` еще аргумент с контекстом и привяжите его через `apply`, тогда в момент вызова `callback` он  будет известен

```
function debounce(callback, delay, context ) {
  let timeout;
    return function() {
      let ctx = context
      clearTimeout( timeout );
      timeout = setTimeout( callback.apply(ctx), delay );
    }
 };
this.minusBtn.addEventListener('click', debounce(remove, 1000, basket));
```

Comment: А basket - это что?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге решил вот так:

```
class ToBasket {
    constructor(element) {
        this.module = element;
        this.i = 1;
        this.bool = false;
        this.basketBtnFst = this.module.querySelector('.j-kt-basket-button-first');
        this.basketBtnScd = this.module.querySelector('.j-kt-basket-button-second');
        this.plusBtn = this.module.querySelector('.j-basket-counter-plus');
        this.minusBtn = this.module.querySelector('.j-basket-counter-minus');
        this.productID = this.module.getAttribute('data-product-id');
        this.bind();
    }

    bind = () => {
        this.showCounterOnLoad();
        this.debounceMethod();
        this.sendToServer();
        this.addToBasket();
        this.removeFromBasket();
        this.pressMinus();
        this.pressPlus();
        this.checkBtn();
    }

    addToBasket = () => {
        ++this.i;
        this.module.querySelector('.j-basket-counter-counter').innerText = this.i;
    }

    sendToServer = () => {
        if (this.bool) {
            BX.ajax.runAction('citfact:sitecore.basket.update', {data: {itemId: this.productID, quantity: this.i}}).then(() => {
                BX.onCustomEvent('OnBasketChange');
            });
        }
        this.bool = true;
    }

    removeFromBasket = () => {
        --this.i;
        console.log(this.i);
        if (this.i > 0) {
            this.module.querySelector('.j-basket-counter-counter').innerText = this.i;
        } else {
            this.i = 0;
            this.module.querySelector('.j-basket-counter').style.display = 'none';
            this.basketBtnFst.querySelector('span').textContent = 'В корзину';
            this.basketBtnFst.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
            this.basketBtnFst.classList.remove('active');
            this.basketBtnFst.classList.remove('d-none');
            this.basketBtnFst.classList.add('add_to_cart');
            this.basketBtnScd.classList.add('d-none');
        }
    }

    showCounterOnLoad = () => {
        BX.ajax.runAction('citfact:sitecore.product.isBasket', {data: {itemId: this.productID}}).then((result) => {
            BX.onCustomEvent('OnBasketChange');
            if (result.data > 0) {
                this.basketBtnFst.classList.add('d-none');
                this.basketBtnScd.classList.remove('d-none');
                document.querySelector('.j-basket-counter').style.display = 'block';
                document.querySelector('.j-basket-counter-counter').innerText = result.data;
                this.i = result.data;
            }
        });
    }

    debounceMethod = (callback, delay = 250) => {
            let timeoutId
            return (...args) => {
              clearTimeout(timeoutId)
              timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                timeoutId = null
                callback(...args)
              }, delay)
            }
    }

    pressMinus = () => {
        this.minusBtn.addEventListener('click', this.removeFromBasket);
        this.minusBtn.addEventListener('click', this.debounceMethod(this.sendToServer, 1000));
    }

    pressPlus = () => {
        this.plusBtn.addEventListener('click', this.addToBasket);
        this.plusBtn.addEventListener('click', this.debounceMethod(this.sendToServer, 1000));
    }

    checkBtn = () => {
        this.basketBtnFst.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (this.i <= 0) {
                this.i = 1;
            }
        });
    }
}

export const initToBasket = () => {
        const list = [...document.querySelectorAll('.j-card-item-container')];
        list.forEach((element) => {
            new ToBasket(element);
        })
}
```

Пришлось использовать два addEventListener на одно событие, потому, что ajax.RunAction должен быть всегда завернут в клик, иначе выполняется немедленно, а все остальные части метода не должны быть завернуты в дибаунсер.